# How can I use search methods other than kd-Tree in PCL Registration?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, pcl

PCL's registration API has [methods](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_registration.html#a3bfafcf5966b90f513f52ff0a7a42f37) to set the search method for source and target points. However, the only supported method appears to be a kd tree. Since I have organized point clouds, I would like to employ PCL's `OrganizedNeighbor` search method in the correspondence estimation.

As far as I can tell, the registration classes use from the search method, or the `CorrespondenceEstimation` containing it these functions

- `nearestKSearch()` -> available for all search methods
- `setInputCloud()` -> available for all search methods
- `setPointRepresentation()` -> only kd Trees have this, for converting points do k-dimensional vectors

So only the point representation stuff seems to be specific to kd trees. When looking at implementing a custom `CorrespondenceEstimation` subclass, it appears to not be supported to use other search methods.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You may want to use the `point-cloud-library` tag, as HP's Page Control Language (PCL) doesn't have registrations or neighbors.